# Comparing daily returns of every stock with S&P500 and sort the most which overperformed

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, finance, yahoo-finance

I need to -download all the historical prices of every stock contained in the S&P500 and the historical price of the index -calculate the daily returns -comparing every daily returns of every stock with the daily returns of S&P500 -sorting a list of the most performing -calculate how many days out of tot they outperformed

This should be the code for downloaded the data:

```
start_date = "2018-01-01"`
end_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
payload = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies%27')
first_table = payload[0]
df = first_table
symbols = df['Symbol'].values.tolist()
n = len(symbols)
data = yf.download(symbols[:5], group_by='Ticker', start=start_date, end=end_date)
snp = yf.download('SPY', start=start_date, end=end_date)`
```

This is the code for calculating the daily returns

```
logRet = np.log(data/data.shift(1))
```

Thank you

Comment: You code contains quite a few errors and does not compile. You should provide provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clearly state your question.

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: What is the code for comparing daily returns of stocks with daily returns of the index and find who outperformed the most and how many times

Comment: Question contains invalid code and seems to be asking us to write the solution rather than to solve an individual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
start_date = "2018-01-01"
end_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
payload = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
first_table = payload[0]
df = first_table
symbols = df['Symbol'].values.tolist()
n = len(symbols)
data = yf.download(symbols[:5], group_by='Ticker', start=start_date, end=end_date)
snp = yf.download('SPY', start=start_date, end=end_date)
```

Then:

```
# close only
data = data[data.columns[data.columns.get_level_values(1) == "Close"]]
data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(1)
snp = snp[["Close"]].rename(columns={"Close": "SNP"})
# daily returns
logRet = np.log(data/data.shift(1))
logRet_snp = np.log(snp/snp.shift(1))
returns = logRet.merge(logRet_snp, left_index=True, right_index=True)
# count where returns are greater than S&P
count = pd.Series()
# don't include S&P, which will last column from merge.
for x in returns.columns[:-1]:
    # new series index x is sum of bool where return is greater than that of S&P
    count.loc[x] = ((returns[x] > returns["SNP"])*1).sum()
# sort in descending order.
count.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
#Out: 
#ABMD    565
#ABBV    543
#ABT     543
#AOS     515
#MMM     494
#dtype: int64
```

Your website link for `pd.read_html` was incorrect, you had a few additional characters on the end.